# Como crear nueva columna Datetime en Dataframe Python a partir de otras columnas donde tengo el dia, mes y año

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

A partir de un Data frame rt en Pyhton con la siguiente estructura

[image: Dataframe]

quiero crear una columna nueva que sea Datetime, con los datos de la columna "Mes" , "Dia" y el año actual.
Estoy tratando de hacerlo con la siguiente instrucción pero me falla:

`rt['Date']=datetime.datetime(date.today().year, rt['Mes'], rt['Dia'])`

Me da este error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-55c5a330e1fb>", line 1, in <module>
    rt['Date']=datetime.datetime(date.today().year, rt['Mes'], rt['Dia'])

  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 118, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás intentando:

```
rt['Date']=datetime.datetime(date.today().year, rt['Mes'], rt['Dia'])
```

no puede funcionar, porque `datetime.datetime()` espera que le pases en cada uno de sus parámetros un año, un mes y un día. Y le pasas en cambio un año, una lista de meses (la columna del dataframe) y una lista de días (otra columna).

Si en cambio usas `pd.to_datetime()` a éste puedes pasarle por ejemplo una lista de cadenas y convertirá todas ellas a fechas, generando una columna de fechas. La lista de cadenas la podemos construir juntando lo que hay en tu `rt["Mes"]` y `rt["Dia"]`, y el año actual, así:

```
>>> year = str(pd.datetime.now().year)
>>> fechas = year + "-" + rt['Mes'].astype(str) + "-" + rt["Dia"].astype(str)
```

La expresión `year + "-" + rt['Mes'].astype(str) + "-" + rt["Dia"].astype(str)` es en realidad vectorial, aunque no lo parezca, porque estamos "concatenando" columnas pandas que tienen cadenas, por lo que en realidad el concatenado se hace fila a fila, y se retorna una columna con los resultados de la concatenación:

```
>>> fechas
0     2019-1-4
1     2019-2-5
2     2019-3-8
3    2019-4-30
4    2019-4-15
5    2019-5-17
dtype: object
```

En esta columna todos los elementos son cadenas, pero le podemos pasar la columna completa a `pd.to_datetime()` y te retornará una columna de objetos `datetime` como buscabas:

```
>>> rt["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(fechas)
>>> rt
   Mes  Dia       Date
0    1    4 2019-01-04
1    2    5 2019-02-05
2    3    8 2019-03-08
3    4   30 2019-04-30
4    4   15 2019-04-15
5    5   17 2019-05-17
```

Answer (score 4):

Primero, `datetime.datetime` espera tres enteros, no iterables. Debes usar `pandas.to_datetime` para construir la serie. El problema es que se espera que el año se proporcione mediante un iterable de la misma longitud que el mes y día.

Puedes solucionarlo creando un iterable con tantos items como filas tiene el DataFrame en los que todos los items sea el año actual.

```
import pandas as pd


rt = pd.DataFrame({"Mes": (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5),
                   "Dia": (4, 5, 8, 30, 15 , 17)
                   })
```

> ```
> >>> rt
>
>    Mes  Dia
> 0    1    4
> 1    2    5
> 2    3    8
> 3    4   30
> 4    4   15
> 5    5   17
> ```

```
year = pd.datetime.now().year
rt['Date']=pd.to_datetime({'year': [year] * rt.shape[0],
                           'month': rt["Mes"],
                           'day': rt['Dia']
                           })
```

> ```
> >>> rt
>
>    Mes  Dia       Date
> 0    1    4 2019-01-04
> 1    2    5 2019-02-05
> 2    3    8 2019-03-08
> 3    4   30 2019-04-30
> 4    4   15 2019-04-15
> 5    5   17 2019-05-17
>
> >>> rt.dtypes
>
> Mes              int64
> Dia              int64
> Date    datetime64[ns]
> dtype: object
> ```