# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo unos datos donde hay una columna con diferentes años y quiero pasarlo a un formato fecha genérico, tomando el mismo mes y día para los diferentes años, para ello he usado:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)
```

Antes de esto me aseguré de pasar los datos en el formato correcto (o eso creo), haciendo uso de:

```
df = df.fillna(0)

df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int)

year = df['Year']
```

Comment: Hola José, bienvenido a [es,so]. No puedes usar `datetime.Datetime` para convertir una serie de datos.Usa `pandas.Datetime`. La pregunta es un posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/278517/15089

Comment: Siguiendo mi respuesta a esa pregunta, en tu caso tendrías solo que hacer `df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime({'year': df["Year"],
                             'month':  [1] * df.shape[0],
                             'day':  [1] * df.shape[0]})`. Si tienes algún problema comenta o actualiza la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Perdona, pero es que soy nuevo en la comunidad y no se muy bien todavía como funciona esto, me sirvio tu ayuda y me gustaría poder valorar tu comentario positivamente, cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola José, es solo un comentario, no te preocupes. Podrías "agradecer" votando positivamente la pregunta y la respuesta o respuestas a la publicación que he marcado como duplicada, pero no tienes aún la [reputación necesaria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) para votar publicaciones. Como digo no te preocupes, me alegro que te sirviera. Para futuras preguntas que hagas, espero que sigas por aquí ;), puedes mirarte: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089). Un saludo.